# Need Help Extracting 4 Nested Lists into Data Frame

Tags: r

The data in question is the result from JSON that I converted to list. The data looks like this:

```
data <- list(query_day = c('Monday'),
              requester = c('John'),
              detail =
                list(list(ID = 1, weight = 200),
                     list(ID = 2, weight = 300),
                     list(ID = 3, weight = 400,
                          detail2 = list(height = 6.5,
                                         gender = 'M',
                                         name = 'John')),
                     list(ID = 4, weight = 500),
                     list(ID = 5, weight = 600,
                          detail2 = list(height = 5.5,
                                         gender = 'F',
                                         name = 'Jane'))))
```

I'm interested in extracting the data that nested in "detail." Since some list has detail 2 but some don't. I applied the following code prior to attempting to extract the data

```
detail <- data[['detail']]
detail_2_cols <- detail[which(sapply(detail, length) == 2)]
detail_3_cols <- detail[which(sapply(detail, length) == 3)]
```

Then I tried two methods that didn't work.

**First Method**

```
result_data.frame <- data.frame(t(sapply(detail_2_cols,c)))
```

This will result in a dataframe (according to `class()`) with ID and weight columns. But the columns are still a list which makes function like `mean()` not usable.

[Dataframe. But columns are lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgclR.png)

**Second Method**

```
result_do.call <-do.call(rbind,lapply(detail_2_cols,data.frame))
```

This works for the example: the result is dataframe and each column is not a list.

The big problem is that when I applied the same code to the dataset, I got

*Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,:  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0*

I think different column should not be an issue as I separated them prior to converting them into a dataframe.

I'd like the output to have ID and weight columns which are not a list as result in the first method.

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjI1n.png)
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3csv5.png)

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Yes, I just added images.

Comment: So are you interested in extracting data from "detail" with `length` 2 ? Also you need to provide us the data on which the code doesn't work to verify that the answers which we provide work on your real data and not just on the sample which you have shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another quick and dirty way to examine the data structure:

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

> z <- data %>% toJSON() %>% fromJSON()
> z$detail
  ID weight detail2.height detail2.gender detail2.name
1  1    200           NULL           NULL         NULL
2  2    300           NULL           NULL         NULL
3  3    400            6.5              M         John
4  4    500           NULL           NULL         NULL
5  5    600            5.5              F         Jane

> z.df <- as.data.frame(z$detail)

> z$detail$detail2
  height gender name
1   NULL   NULL NULL
2   NULL   NULL NULL
3    6.5      M John
4   NULL   NULL NULL
5    5.5      F Jane
```

*HERE'S HOW YOU GET IT TO ACT LIKE A DATA FRAME* (kludge but effective):

```
> zzz <- read.table(textConnection(captureOutput(print(z.df))), 
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> zzz
  ID weight detail2.height detail2.gender detail2.name
1  1    200           NULL           NULL         NULL
2  2    300           NULL           NULL         NULL
3  3    400            6.5              M         John
4  4    500           NULL           NULL         NULL
5  5    600            5.5              F         Jane

> str(zzz)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ID            : int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ weight        : int  200 300 400 500 600
 $ detail2.height: chr  "NULL" "NULL" "6.5" "NULL" ...
 $ detail2.gender: chr  "NULL" "NULL" "M" "NULL" ...
 $ detail2.name  : chr  "NULL" "NULL" "John" "NULL" ...
```

Now you can get to exactly data frame you want in the image you posted:

```
> final.df <- zzz %>% replace(.=="NULL", NA) %>% 
    filter(!complete.cases(.)) %>% select(ID,weight) %>% 
    as.tibble()

> final.df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     ID weight
  <int>  <int>
1     1    200
2     2    300
3     4    500
```

Answer (score 0):

for a quick and dirty fix you could try `rlist` library

```
library(rlist)

rlist::list.flatten(data) %>% dplyr::bind_rows()
```

You will get back a tibble on which you could apply `dplyr::select(contains("detail"))` to pull out the columns you want.